# multiprocessing python, two process

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, multiprocessing

When sensor1 is detected, Process1 is activated.
Is there a way to make Process2 operate when sensor2 is detected while Process1 is running??
I would appreciate if you can tell me how.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Manager

def p1(queue):
    for i in range(1000):
        print('p1 : %s' %i)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        
    print('p1 end') 
    
def p2(queue):
    for i in range(1000):
        print('p2 : %s' %i)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    print('p2 end')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('start')
    GPIO.add_event_detect(Sensor1, GPIO.RISING, bouncetime=800)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(Sensor2, GPIO.FALLING, bouncetime=1000)
    queue = Manager().Queue()
    
    while True:
        if GPIO.event_detected(Sensor1):
            #smooth(queue)
            process1 = Process(target = p1, args = (queue,))
            process1.start()
            process1.join()
            
        
        elif GPIO.event_detected(Sensor2):
            process2 = Process(target = p2, args=(queue,))
            process2.start()
            process2.join()
```

Comment: If you `join()` a process right after starting it, there will be no real multiprocessing.

Comment: Will removing process1.join() fix the problem?

Comment: You have created a queue but it is totally unclear where this queue comes into play and how process1 and process2 are related or communicate with one another. If you remove the `join`, you will be creating a new process every time a new event is detected. I am sure there must be a better solution, especially if you have created a queue.